# Is it possible to run Postgres in Google App Engine Flexible?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to run postgres (essentially, a non-HTTP service) in a custom Google App Engine Flexible container? Or will I be forced to use Google's Cloud SQL solution?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: You could do that, but don’t. It’s better to externalize the persistent data storage.

Yes, it is possible to run a PostgreSQL database as a microservice (named simply a 'service' in Google Cloud Platform) in a custom Google App Engine Flexible container. However, that raises another important question, namely *why* would you like to run an SQL database inside a container. This is a risky solution, unless you are perfectly sure about what you are doing and how to manage that.

Typical container orchestration is based on stateless services which means that they are not intended to store persistent data. This kind of containers do have some form of storage sometimes, like NoSQL databases for cache or user session information. This data is not persistent, it can be lost during restarts or destruction of instances in an agile containerized application environment. PostgreSQL databases are rather used as stateful services and do not suit the aforementioned model. Putting such database into a container, one can run into problems like data corruption or direct concurrency when accessing some shared data directory. Also, in Google App Engine Flexible it’s not possible to add a shared persistent disk, the volumes are attached to instances and destroyed together with them. Much safer solution is keeping the SQL database in an external, durable storage, as Cloud SQL that you have mentioned. There are numerous blog posts and articles that elaborate this issue with the stateless/stateful services, like [this one](https://mesosphere.com/blog/stateful-services-black-sheep-container-world/).

It should be mentioned that if you are to use the container in a local environment or for test/development (and you are not looking for a durable state of the database), putting a PostgreSQL inside a container should be perfectly ok. Also, if you design a special way of splitting your data across instances this could work fine, as the guys did with their MySQL servers in [this article](https://medium.com/@Pinterest_Engineering/sharding-pinterest-how-we-scaled-our-mysql-fleet-3f341e96ca6f). So once again, the idea of putting a PostgreSQL database in a container should be carefully thought-out, especially that there are so many options of a safe externalization of such a service.

And just as a side note, you are not forced to use Cloud SQL. The database can be hosted on Compute Engine, another cloud provider, on premises, or can be managed by a third-party vendor. In case of hosting it in Compute Engine the application is able to communicate with the database inside the same project using the internal IP of the Compute Engine instance. Using [Cloud Launcher](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/) you can quickly deploy PostgreSQL and other popular databases to Compute Engine. Check these [Google docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-third-party-databases) for more information about using third-party databases.